# ASP.NET MVC, Ninject, single instance per request for multiple constructors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, ninject, unit-of-work

Im trying to implement an unit of work pattern by passing an unit of work instance into my repositories.

Relevant code from Global.asax.

```
public class SiteModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load() {        
       Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<SqlUnitOfWork>()
                          .InRequestScope()
                          .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entities"].ConnectionString);

       Bind<IProductRepository>().To<ProductRepository>();
       Bind<ICategoryRepository>().To<CategoryRepository>();
    }
}
```

Repository constructors:

```
public class ProductRepository {
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    public ProductRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}

public class CategoryRepository {
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    public CategoryRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

What i want is that a maximum of 1 instance of `SqlUnitOfWork` is created per request and is passed into my repositories (via their respective constructors).

Is the `InRequestScope()` method on the `IUnitOfWork` binding enough? If not how can i achieve this?

Comment: Yes it is. Only one instance of `IUnitOfWork` will be given to any class that requests it (via constructor injection or calls to the kernel's `.Get<>` etc.)

Comment: we're using the same pattern as you (except we use structuremap for DI). Ours look slightly different. We new up a sqlcontext per httprequest, not a UoW. One request may have multiple UoW's.

Comment: Baddie - add you comment as an answer so it can be upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code you have will work fine. Only one instance of `IUnitOfWork` will be given to any class that requests it (via constructor/property injection or calls to the kernel's `.Get<>` etc.)