# How to inject the same instance of a class with Ninject?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject-2

I am using Ninject for IoC. I have the following classes.

```
// Repository
public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository, IUnitOfWorkRepository
{
  private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
  private EFDbContext efDbContext;

  public EFProductRepository(IUnitOfWork uow)
  {
    unitOfWork = uow;
    efDbContext = new EFDbContext();
  }
  //
}

// Controller
public class ProductController : Controller
{
  private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
  private IProductRepository productRepository;

  public ProductController(IUnitOfWork uow, IProductRepository repo)
  {
    unitOfWork = uow;
    productRepository = repo;
  }
}
```

Currently my ninject bindings are as follow which assign new instance of the concrete class for the interface.

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();
```

using my ninject controller factory, I need to inject same instance of the IUnitOfWork class to the ProductController and EFProductRepository. Please guide me.

Comment: Use `InRequestScope` method. Example can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897690/asp-net-mvc-ninject-single-instance-per-request-for-multiple-constructors.